# How to pass multiple parameters to the parametrized query in c# using DbParameter?

Tags: c#, .net, database

I want to develop generalized application which can works with all type of databases (Oracle, MySQL, SQLite). So I have provide different data source to the each form from one common place.

And I also want to use parametrized query who can accept multiple parameters. I am unable to to pass multiple parameters using DbParameter, it works fine with single parameter query but 
not with many.

So please help me...

```
            dbconnect dc = new dbconnect();//class which contain data source name
            DbConnection con;
            DbCommand cmd;
            DbDataReader dr;
            DbProviderFactory df;
            DataAdapter da;

            df = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(dbconnect.dbprovider);
            con = df.CreateConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = dbconnect.sqlstr;
            con.Open();
            cmd = df.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "update customer set" + " name='@name'," + "address='@address'," + "phone='@phone' " + "where code='@code';";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            DbDataAdapter daa = df.CreateDataAdapter();
            daa.UpdateCommand = cmd;

            DbParameter param = df.CreateParameter();

            param.ParameterName = "@name";
            param.Value = txtname.Text;

            param.ParameterName = "@address";
            param.Value = txtadd.Text;

            param.ParameterName = "@phone";
            param.Value = txtphone.Text;

            param.ParameterName = "@code";
            param.Value = txtcode.Text;
            daa.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(param);
            daa.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            **But this not working.**
```

Comment: Please really look into disposing your connections/commands/readers/adapters when you're done with them, preferably with using blocks, or at least calling `Dispose()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only creating one parameter

```
        DbParameter param = df.CreateParameter();

        param.ParameterName = "@name";
        param.Value = txtname.Text;
```

etc...

You need to create a new  `DbParameter` for each one

```
        DbParameter param = df.CreateParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@name";
        param.Value = txtname.Text;
        daa.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(param);

        param = df.CreateParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@address";
        param.Value = txtadd.Text;
        daa.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(param);
```

etc....

and add each one to the command.

Comment: daa.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(param);  Where i need to insert them.

Answer (score 4):

This code is the problem:

```
DbParameter param = df.CreateParameter();

param.ParameterName = "@name";
param.Value = txtname.Text;

param.ParameterName = "@address";
param.Value = txtadd.Text;

param.ParameterName = "@phone";
param.Value = txtphone.Text;

param.ParameterName = "@code";
param.Value = txtcode.Text;
daa.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(param);
```

You're creating *one* parameter object, changing its `ParameterName` and `Value` properties several times, and then adding that *single* parameter to the command. That's going to leave you with a command with a single parameter, the name and value of which will be the last ones you set.

Instead, you want to add several *separate* parameters, so you need to call `Parameters.Add` several times. For example:

```
DbParameter nameParam = df.CreateParameter();
nameParam.ParameterName = "@name";
nameParam.Value = txtname.Text;
daa.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(nameParam);

DbParameter addressParam = df.CreateParameter();
addressParam.ParameterName = "@address";
addressParam.Value = txtadd.Text;
daa.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(addressParam);
// etc
```

This could be made a lot cleaner by extracting a method to add a parameter with the given name and value:

```
AddParameter(daa.UpdateCommand, "@name", txtname.Text);
AddParameter(daa.UpdateCommand, "@address", txtadd.Text);
// etc
```

Comment: do you know how to use DbParameterCollection ? I search alot but could not find any relevant thing even on msdn there is no example

Comment: @WaqarJanjua: Well I know enough to suspect that if you want multiple parameters, you should call `Add` more than once :)

Answer (score 0):

DbDataAdapter is normally used for bulk or multiple row update.
For single row update use DbCommand.

```
DbProviderFactory df = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(dbconnect.dbprovider);             
            using(DbConnection con = df.CreateConnection())
            {
                con.ConnectionString = "dbconnect.sqlstr";              
                DbCommand cmd = df.CreateCommand(); 
                cmd.CommandText = "update customer set" + " name='@name'," + "address='@address'," + "phone='@phone' " + "where code='@code';";
                cmd.Connection = con; 

                DbParameter param1 = df.CreateParameter(); 
                param1.ParameterName = "@name"; 
                param1.Value = txtname.Text;

                DbParameter param2 = df.CreateParameter(); 
                param2.ParameterName = "@address"; 
                param2.Value = txtadd.Text; 

                DbParameter param3 = df.CreateParameter(); 
                param3.ParameterName = "@phone"; 
                param3.Value = txtphone.Text; 

                DbParameter param4 = df.CreateParameter(); 
                param4.ParameterName = "@code"; 
                param4.Value = txtcode.Text;

                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```