# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'ddlcataglist'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
Controller
```

> ```
> public class ProController : Controller
>     {
>         string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OnlineInventoryDB"].ConnectionString;
> ```

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            Get_catagory();
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("Create")]
        public ActionResult Create_Post(Product product)
        {


            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                pro.AddProduct(product);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View();
        }



        public void Get_catagory()
        {

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("DDLCatagory", con);
            sda.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);

            List<SelectListItem> ddlcatlist = new List<SelectListItem>();

            foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                ddlcatlist.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = dr["Catagory"].ToString(), Value = dr["Cat_ID"].ToString() });
            }
            ViewData["cataglistddl"] = ddlcatlist;
        }


    }
```

Strongly Typed

@model BuisnessLogics.Product

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Product</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Prod_Catagory, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("ddlcataglist", ViewData["cataglistddl"] as List<SelectListItem>,"Select Cataegory", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Prod_Catagory, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cost, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cost, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cost, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

At time of page submission the There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'ddlcataglist' error is shown and the page is not submitted.

Comment: Also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - the key word being **minimal**. 99% of this code is irrelevant to your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rebind your dropdown in post method also.

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Create")]
 public ActionResult Create_Post(Product product)
 {
      Get_catagory();
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
          pro.AddProduct(product);
          return RedirectToAction("Index");
      }

    return View();
 }
```

Comment: `ViewData["cataglistddl"]` is already `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` - this is just pointless extra overhead

Comment: @StephenMuecke Actually the problem is he did not binded the drop down value in post method.

Comment: I know - that is why I duped it :)

Comment: red error line showing under the ViewData["cataglistddl"]

Comment: No issues, that is normal due to version of razor.  Please run the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523165/how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-to-the-parametrized-query-in-c-sharp-using-dbpar

Comment: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Prod_Catagory, ViewData["cataglistddl"] as List<SelectListItem>, "SELECT CATEGORY", new { @class = "form-control" })                                                         
  Using above my drop down list is saving value instead of text to database. How could i fix this.

Comment: ddlcatlist.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = dr["Catagory"].ToString(), Value = dr["Cat_ID"].ToString() });  Here you do modification.

Comment: and what exactly it should b?

Comment: if you want textvalue in both value field and text field then just map text in both field.  ddlcatlist.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = dr["Catagory"].ToString(), Value = dr["Catagory"].ToString()});